# Google plus button plusone.google.com post error

Tags: button, google-plus

I just put the standard button code from https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/ on my page:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" data-href="www.artkiddo.pl"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.___gcfg = {lang: 'pl'};

    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```

...and button doesn't work (just turns into exclamation mark).
I've checked console errors with Chrome, and I get 5 "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL..." errors, but from what I've read it's nothing to worry about.
On the network tab, I get multiple new entries when I press the button, and one of them turns red. It's:

```
plusone.google.com
plusone.google.com/wm/2/_/socialgraph/lookup/circles

Method: POST
Status: (canceled)
Type: Pending
Initiator: plusone.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/p1sb/p1sb,shbx,shbl/rt=j/ver=fV4vfloJULA.pl./sv=1/am=!pnCXnPKXMfcZg__Mof_kNZg/d=1/rs=AItRSTNSWuIKSyAuqWEhkyxtmaIGMuTd9w:349
Size: 13B, Script: 0B
Time: 130ms, Latency: 0.0days
```

with headers:

```
Request URL:https://plusone.google.com/wm/2/_/socialgraph/lookup/circles/?ct=2&m=true&_reqid=13606&rt=j

Request Headers:
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Origin:https://plusone.google.com
Referer:https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=pl&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.artkiddo.pl%2Fwww.artkiddo.pl&t=1352688390637&source=widget&referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.artkiddo.pl%2F&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fgapi%2F__features__%2Frt%3Dj%2Fver%3DB6wIx_C7M_g.pl.%2Fsv%3D1%2Fam%3D!SYcw6mesaJeITQu65A%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItRSTPsCd84_NviKQ9qgnvGTMBi5CiVIQ
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
X-Same-Domain:1

Query String Parameters
ct:2
m:true
_reqid:13606
rt:j

Form Data
at:AObGSAiDvI5JtHm1Zi8ePoQO03qTurn2Zg:135268840558
:
```

Preview, response, and cookies has nothing in it.

To be honest, I have no idea where to start looking for solution to that. I've checked other similar questions here on stack overflow, but none of answers helps. Page is definitely accessible for google (I use analytics, indexing returns no problems, etc.), my google account gives no signs of being banned, cookie settings is at default, error comes up within less then a second (so I don't expect it to be time-out problem), and there is no problem with clicking it on different sites.

Any tips on what may be a problem, and where to start looking for a solution?

edit:
seems that all I wrote here is not relevant. After couple of reloads, now I get only 2 errors in console, and no errors in network tab, but the button still does not work.
And... after next reload it's back again as I wrote from the beginning. Seems like very random thing with those errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data-href parameter is not a valid URL. You should prefix it will `http://`

The service is probably treating this like a relative URL and is not able to fetch the page.

Comment: Good they didn't mention that on plugin page. Thanks. Works like charm with prefix.

Comment: Some can say that "URL" should be enough, as RFC 1738 specifies that URL should contain protocol part, but... nowadays more amateurs write their web sites (like me), and most of them doesn't even know what is RFC document. So I believe it's good idea to write such pages with them in mind.
I know what RFC is, just because of the times of using FidoNET for connecting the world, and... I just got lazy now, with those user-friendly tools everywhere. I believe I'm not the only one.
Cheers.